# как обновить создание блоков через ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте.

У меня массив постоянно пополняется с сервера, и по ng-repeat создаются блоки на странице. Можно ли как-то после того, как добавится в массив новый объект, удалить все предыдущие блоки и написать по новой? Или чтобы функция не обходила опять весь массив (тогда идут дубликаты), а просто добавляла новые блоки к уже существующим?

Пример когда:
HTML:

```
1
<!Doctype>
<html ng-app="catChatApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Стартовая страница</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js">
</script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">
<div id="confirmation" class="divsStyles"></div>
<div id="errorDiv" class="divsStyles"></div>
<div id="holder"></div>
<menu>
<li>Разместить новую заявку</li>
<li>|</li>
<li>О нас</li>
</menu>
<ng-view></ng-view> //Отображаем все пути тут
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</html>
```

код HTML где у меня проблема: (весь не буду вставлять только тот блок)

```
<div id="wrapperForWontersTalk" class="divsStyles"><button 
type="button" value="closeList">X</button>
<div class="divsStyles, userDiv" ng-repeat="user in wontToTolk track 
by $index"> //C этим блоком проблема
    <div class="userPhoto"></div>
    <div class="userDivsInformation" data-name="{{user.name}}" data-
id="{{user.ID}}"><p>{{user.name+', '+user.age}}<div>Сейчас <span 
style="color: green">{{user.where}}</span></div></p></div>
    <div class="userDivsInformation"><p>{{user.country+', 
'+user.city}}</p><p>{{user.information}}</p></div>
    <button ng-
click="onfirmationToChatFunction(user)">Ответить</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Пример заполения:

```
$scope.socket.on('sendToTalk', function(wonter, chosenID){
if($scope.ID == chosenID) {
$scope.wontToTalkCounter++;
$scope.wontToTolk.push(wonter);
    alert($scope.wontToTolk.length); //Прилетает 2 раза почему-то 2 одинаковых блока хотя $scope.wontToTalkCounter увеличивается на 1
if($scope.wontToTalkCounter == 1 || $scope.wontToTalkCounter >= 5) 
$scope.rightWord = ' человек';
else $scope.rightWord = ' человека';
}
$scope.$apply();
});
```

тут отсылаем запрос (1 раз):

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
let target = e.target;
//Клики по кнопкам
if(target.value == 'send'){
    $scope.socket.emit('sendToTalk', $scope.ID, $scope.lastChosenID);
    holder.style.display = 'none';
    confirmation.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: `ng-repeat` будет перерисовывать все блоки из массива при изменении.  Чтобы обновить данные `$scope.apply()`

Comment: добавил, но track by $index всеравно надо использовать и теперь приходит по 2 блока вместо одного (ну 1 пользователь отсылает запрос приходит 2 его блока)

Comment: Приведите пример кода, заполнения масива в контроллере и его отображение во view

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: тебе надо разобраться что ты шлешь и что получаешь по сокету

Comment: ну смотретите систему я шлю свой ИД и ИД блока на какой кликнул. после мой ИД на сервере проверяется и присылает мой профиль в виде объекта wonter ну и wonter должен прийти и отображаться у lastChosenID. Все работает, но почему то приходит 2 ответа. На сервере ток что проверил, он делат только 1 ответ и 1 объет отсылает

Comment: здесь логическая ошибка: `$scope.wontToTolk.push(wonter);
    alert($scope.wontToTolk.length);` ты проверяешь длину после добавления _одного_ объекта, как ты определил, что пришло 2? если по тому, что вывелось 2 - то это просто значит, что в этом массиве уже был какой-то элемент. Еще вариант, ты несколько раз подписываешься на события, возможно даже в нескольких местах.

Comment: В общем опять все сводится  к тому, что без [mcve] можно только пальцем в небо тыкать

Comment: вот такое `document.onclick = function(e) {`, да еще и в ангуляре - выглядит странно

Comment: их приходит по одному, алетр выводится 2 раза синхронно.
document.onclick думаю исправлю, просто там кнопка создается через innerHTML и в ней не работал ng-click.
их правда приходит по 2 так-как я поробовал ещё запросы отсылать и опять приходило 2 блока (4 уже в сумме)

Comment: ладно я ещё поработаю, сменю on click и попробую нормально переделать